# Angular 8 /Firebase: how do I set the displayName when creating user with email and password?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

After reading so many posts and empty(or not?) solutions, I figured that the best thing was to post of my own. So my goal is just to get the displayName of the user so in a list of posts or whatever, the authorship doesnt look ugly with a uid...
Here's what I find relevant for the problem:

Signup reactive form, later called on onInit:

```
createForm() {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group(
      {
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        email: ["", [Validators.required]],
        password: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
        retype: ["", Validators.required]
      },
      {
        validator: PasswordValidators.passwordsShouldMatch
      }
    );
  }
```

The submit method:

```
 onSubmit() {
    if (this.registerForm.invalid) return;
    this.registered = true
    this.authService.registerUser(this.email.value, this.password.value).then(data=>{
      console.log(data)
    })

  }
```

The authService calling the uid and the register method:

```
 constructor( private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user=>{
      this.userId = user.uid;
     })
   }


registerUser(email:string, password:string) {
      return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((result) => {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          console.log(result.user)
        }).catch((error) => {
          window.alert(error.message)
        })
    }
```

When logging this line `this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user=>{
          this.userId = user.uid;`, actually logging the user, i can see the whole object and the displayName, but since the register method only accepts 2 arguments, email and pass, how to I workaround this? I've tried an uproach dealing with updateprofile but I got stuck on an error...Is there any solution? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wan to set the display name of a user account, you won't be able to do that at the time of account creation using createUserWithEmailAndPassword.  You'll have to perform a followup call to [updateProfile()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateprofile) on the user object you get back.

```
result.user.updateProfile({
    displayName: ...
})
.then(...)
.catch(...)
```

You will obviously have to pass along the name in the call to `registerUser()`.

Comment: thank you @Doug, but the code you've displayed..is it inside of what function? RegistarUser?

Comment: Inside the promise callback for createUserWithEmailAndPassword where you log the user.