# Is it possible to create user with email and password and add username(display name) immediately?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

When you create user using firebase auth on flutter, you able to set email and password while creating user. I also need to set display name while creating user, but i found only way to set display name after creating user.

I used code like this

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: eMail.text.trim(),
  password: passWord.text.trim(),
)
    .then((uC){
  uC.user!
      .updateDisplayName(userName.text.trim());
}
```

But this isn't what I need

Comment: The purpose of firebase authentication is to create and maintain a unique and secure ID for a user. It has limited support for other user attributes. To maintain these other attributes, such as display name, you should use a database. The answer below suggests one such database.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use fireStore to add user detail to firebase after SignUp is successful.

```
Future<bool> signUp(String name,String email,String phone,String password,BuildContext context) async {
    try{

      //loading dialog starts
      showLoadingDialog(context);
      UserCredential credential = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

      //if user creation is success, create a user model
      if(credential.user == null) return false;
      UserModel user = UserModel(
        uId: credential.user!.uid.toString(),
        name: name,
        email: credential.user!.email.toString(),
        phone: phone,
      );

      //and upload user model to firebase
      await _fireStore.collection('users').doc(credential.user!.uid).set(user.toMap()).then((value){
        showSnackBar(context, "Sign Up Successful!");
      });
      return true;
    }on FirebaseAuthException catch(exception){
      showSnackBar(context, getMessageFromErrorCode(exception.code));
      return false;
    }finally{
      //pops loading dialog
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the Flutter (and other client-side SDKs) it will always require an extra API call to set the display name of the user.

If creating the user and setting their display name atomically is a requirement for you app, consider using the Admin SDK in a trusted environment  (such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run) to perform that action atomically, creating an endpoint for your this, and then calling that from your app.

Also see:

- [Creating User with Email, password, display name and photoURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60627643/creating-user-with-email-password-display-name-and-photourl)